# Access 2013 multi value field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm creating a table for a college major. The table is called `major`. The columns  will be `majorID`, `majorName`, and `requiredCourses`.

In Access how can I make `requiredCourses` a multivalue field? Required courses will be around 20 courses.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a one-to-many relationship. The way is is usually done is like this:

1. You need to create a new table for the courses. Call it course. The table will contain CourseID, CourseName, etc. CourceID will be a primary key of this table
2. You will need to create another table that will act as a link between your major and your course tables. The table can be called something like majorCourses. The table will contain at least these two fields: majorID and courseID (you can of course add more fields, like dateAdded, isInactive, etc.).

To link your tables you will need to JOIN these tables, like this:

```
SELECT m.majorID, m.majorName, c.courseID, c.CourseName
FROM major m 
INNER JOIN (majorCourses mc INNER JOIN course c ON mc.courseID = c.courseID) 
ON m.majorID = mc.majorID
```